# XML data not Complete when reading from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I'm executing an sql query through C# to fetch XML data as follows, but in the string `getxml_string` the XML data is not complete as compared to the data on SQL server, I feel I'm doing something wrong with the `getxml_string`, but can't figure out:

```
string getxml = "some query"
DataTable getxml_table = SQLClass.GETSQL(getxml , conn);
var doc = new XmlDocument();
string getxml_string = getxml_table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(x => x[0].ToString()).First();
 doc.LoadXml(getxml_string);
```

In GETSQL it's nothing fancy just as follows:

```
public static DataTable GETSQL(string sqller, SqlConnection connection)
        {

           DataTable data_table = new DataTable();
           connection.Open();
           using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqller, connection))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command );


                        adapter.Fill(data_table);

                    connection.Close();
                        return data_table ;
            }

}
```

Comment: Not related to your current question, but `GETSQL` is a really bad idea for a method. Your essentially forcing the SQL interface to be based on a single string at a time which makes using parameters impossible. And this is bad because "use parameters" is the habit you should get into to avoid `SQL Injection`.

Comment: Okay, I found the problem. I problem is certainly my `getxml_string` as I can see from the dataset visualizer. Here I'm doing a .FIRST(), so it's just fetching the first line. How do I get all the lines.

Comment: You may not be getting all the data.  Increase timeout. command.CommandTimeout = 300; //in seconds, default is 30

Comment: @jdweng, I can see in the datatable (`getxml_table`) it has fetched all the data. BUt now the problem is reading out of the datatable. I'm using a `.first` in the `getxml_string`. So probably because of that. I'm having trouble reading out of the datatable.

Comment: Need to see portion of xml to determine the fix.  There are lots of methods to parse xml and not sure the appropriate method in this case.

Comment: If you are parsing a string use doc.Parse(string).

Comment: I don't have an issue with the `doc.loadxml`. As I said my issue is the`getxml_string` linq query. How to read data from the data table as xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
List<datarow> list =  getxml_table.AsEnumberable().ToList();
```